# Get Project one exception into Project Two

Tags: java, exception

how to get project one exception into project two

i have two projects in my second project my method has try catch block

i calling that method in my first project

i want get my second project exception into first project

any one have this situation

**project two**

```
public ProjectTwoClass{

 public static String projectTwoMethod(String someThing){
   try{
      .....
   }catch(Exception e){
     throw new RuntimeException("message");
   }
 }
}
```

**Project One**

```
public ProjectOneClass  {
 public String projectOneMethod(String something){
   try{
     ProjectTwoClass.projectTwoMethod(someThing);
   }catch (Exception e){
     ....
      //i want here
   }
 }
}
```

i dont want to delete project two try catch block

any ideas could be appreciated thanks in advance

Thanks
pradeep

Comment: What is the problem? You don't need to delete either try-catch block, the first block will throw a new exception up the call stack.

Comment: This should already work.  What is the problem?

Comment: i want to get the project two exception in my project one

Comment: I am baffled as to why this is sitting at +3. The code already works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is catching the exception and throwing a new one. **You can rethrow the exception** instead.
To do that you just have to do `throw e` and specify that the method can throw exception by adding `throws Exception`.

```
public ProjectTwoClass{

 public static String projectTwoMethod(String someThing) throws Exception {
   try{
      .....
   }catch(Exception e){
     throw e; // Rethrow the exception instead of creating a new one.
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes i got it, you are right thank you very very much, your answer is really helpful